# Help to identify door manufacturer

Tags: doors

I can't find any name on the exterior door that needs to be adjusted, weather stripping replaced, etc. I've had two "handyman" types adjust it but it's still very hard to lock (have to wiggle it massively back & forth), doesn't seal well, etc. I hope I can go to the manufacturer to find a good repair person or if the door needs to be replaced.

[image]

[image: Door]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Additional picture would help. What kind of lock are you talking about? There doesn't appear to be a deadbolt  so are you referring to the knob? Where isn't it sealing well?

Comment: usually the manufacturer is on a plate on the top surface of the door or the hinge jamb side.

Comment: Lots of (current and historical) regional door and window manufacturers; might help if you edit your question with where you are in the world.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger I got a ladder out - nothing on the top of the door! There's nothing on the hinge/jamb and the glass has an unreadable # on the very bottom corner.  There is a "1116" stamped on the door too.

@ blarg Not talking about the lock itself (it's Amesbury I believe). It's a tall door -  you hold the handle up then turn the deadbolt to lock. Basically, there's a good amount f play (front to back) the weather stripping/trim isn't holding it in the right place to lock & it binds when trying to open.  I'll try to add pics.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Austin TX USA (around 2011-2014 is my guess when it was installed)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call a door specialist.  Check door refinishers as well. In my location there are some that refinish or adjust or even rebuild all types of doors.

Most will have or know where to get any weatherstriping that needs replacing.
They know how to adjust a plethora of doors as well. That's their job.

Comment: This is not helpful nor is it answering the question of the post.

Comment: @ Austin,  Finding the manufacturer of the door is like looking for a needle in a haystack, in a dark room with your eyes closed.  Then still the adjustments and repairs need to be done.  My answer is the path of least resistance for the OP to get what they desire.

Comment: I'm in for the needle - it's a high-end door that someone has to know. Point me to the right person and happy to not care make/model of door. The funny thing is the issue still exists "just get a person" - normal fixers have no idea what to do with this door...hence my qustion about who makes it.

Comment: @austin, Have you tried a door specialist?  My  money is on "no".  That is why you are posting here with hopes.

Comment: Real door guys <> handymen. Look for local door places (even better if they are door *hardware* suppliers) and ask them for a reference. Keywords: ‘I have a fancy multipoint locking door that needs maintenance’.

Comment: A "high end" door, @Austin, might have been custom built by a local woodworker. It's likely she would have put a stamp on it of some sort, though. I'd suggest calling your local cabinet shops/woodworkers and asking around if anyone made a door for your house. A cabinet shop probably would _not_ have done so, but might point you in the direction of local companies that would make doors. Even if you can't find _the_ maker, you'll find someone with expertise who would be able to fix yours up for you.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate & others thanks for the recommendations. I'll call a local door supplier and see who they recommend. 

It's for sure not custom build - I have 3 French doors and two like this one all with the same logo/stamp. The "A" logo thing that is shown in the picture belongs to someone. :) Was hoping someone would recognize the logo

Comment: Even if it was custom built (very unlikely, imho), the hardware is off the shelf, and that’s where the expertise has to be.

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure that the door (or at least its appurtenances, e.g. weatherstrip, seals, etc.) was manufactured by Amesbury. Amesbury was acquired by Truth (a long-tenure US fenestration company) in 2013 and the company is now known as [AmesburyTruth.](https://www.amesburytruth.com/)

Their current logo seems to incorporate both the Amesbury (very similar to your pic) and Truth logos:

[image]

Comment: I think you're on to something here!  The A in the logo looks very similar, I'm gonna keep digging on their site to see if I can identify the component of the door while I search for a good local door specialist.

Comment: Cool; their site lists dealers and service companies across the US.